# rails way to join models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose I have a one-to-many association

in the Author class

```
has_many :books
```

in the School class

```
has_many :books
```

in the Book class

```
belongs_to :authors
belongs_to :schools
```

Now hitting the `SchoolsController#some_method`, with `params[:id]` as a get request parameter, I want to retrieve all the authors of books that are in some `param[:id]` school. So I wrote this that works

```
@shools = Books.where(school_id: params[:id])
@books ||= []
@books.each do |book|
   @books << book.user
end
```

but I don't think it is the correct rails way to do that. Could someone help ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about working code that needs refactoring. It should be on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins) method:

```
@authors = Author.joins(:books).where(books: {school_id: params[:id]})
```

Answer (score 4):

There area a few things wrong with your code.

First, the `belongs_to` params in your Book class should be singular. `belongs_to :author` and `belongs_to :school`

In your controller, you never use the `@shools` variable, I imagine it's supposed to read `@books`?

Appending to the `@books` array from within the each loop is a bad idea seeing as you're looping over `@books` in the first place.

Once you have all that fixed, you can get your authors back like this (as Marek mentioned in his answer):

```
@authors = Author.joins(:books).where(books: {school_id: params[:id]})
```

Comment: Great addition to my (probably too) short answer. +1.